# How to check if a Facebook user account is restricted via API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

[image: User account restricted]

The [account quality](https://www.facebook.com/accountquality) page of a user account shows account restricted and I am unable use the account for advertising.

Is it possible to check if a user account is restricted using any Facebook API endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the request that you need:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/graphql?access_token=TOKEN&doc_id=3797389657004143&variables={assetOwnerId:USERID}&method=post
```

Just replace the TOKEN and USERID params to the ones that you need and you'll get a result like this:

```
{
   "data":{
      "assetOwnerData":{
         "name":"Cenneth Orlino",
         "profile_picture":{"uri":""},
         "advertising_restriction_info":{
            "is_restricted":false,
            "restriction_date":null,
            "restriction_type":null,
            "status":"NOT_RESTRICTED",
            "additional_parameters":null
         },
... Many more useful info here ...
```

You need the `advertising_restriction_info` field.

Another way to do the same check is to query an ad account for the field `is_user_allowed_to_advertise`:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/act_ADACCOUNTID/?access_token=TOKEN&fields=is_user_allowed_to_advertise
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking to determine if your Facebook ad account is restricted, you can make a request to the following endpoint:

`${version}/${ad-account-id}?fields=id,name,account_status`.

Once you've made the request, you'll want to check the `account_status` field.

If the value is `2`, `101`, or `202`, then your ad account is indeed restricted.

Comment: Any chance you can link me the documentation for these status codes? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: sure, here is it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/#fields